# Improve performance of .Net core analytics application using Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-stream-analytics

We have an analytics application developed using .net core, which combines the output from two existing data sources and then responds to customer requests for data about specific companies. Application is deployed to azure. One of the data sources is another analytics model, which once per day, just after midnight, generates a benchmark file. The other data source is an internal API which provides pricing information. The records contain around 30,000 companies data, where in  calculation using the benchmark file and pricing data is taking approx. 5 minutes/company, and the result(10KB of JSON) is valid for all requests for that company until the following day. We are trying to reduce the processing time/company (ideally it needs to be a second or two(Max)).

Does Azure Stream Analytics/Azure Data bricks help to reduce processing time?

Any inputs will Help. Thanks

Comment: really hard to help without any code. I don't think it's a tool problem, but how you're solving it. To me, rather than recalculating everything, a smart way would be create a delta, and just work on the items that changed the price (or other information).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Stream Analytics is a stream processing service. It applies business logic defined in SQL in near real time (very low latency) on a stream of incoming events. The main applications are: event driven architectures, streaming ETL, and real time dashboarding.

Here you process data in batch ("once per day"), so Azure Stream Analytics is not the right service for this use case.

Depending on which language you want to use to express your business logic, Azure Databricks, Azure Data Factory and/or Azure Synapse SQL Pool are the main tools to pick from.